# Pytest, directory structure and import errors

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, directory, pytest

I'm coding my first project in Python and what I found frustrating about Python and PyTest is that it's complicated to make the directory structure and importing modules working.

I have a directory structure like this:

```
Football
  football
    __init__.py
    file1.py
    file2.py
    file3.py
    main.py
  tests
    context.py
    test_file1.py
    test_file2.py
    test_file3.py
```

Obviously, the names of the files are different than in the above example.

When I want to import a class File2 from file2.py in file1.py or main.py, then in file1.py or main.py I write:

```
from file2 import File2
```

The content of my context.py file is:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
import football
```

This is how the content of one of the tests files (for example 'test_file1.py') look like more or less:

```
from context import football
from football.file1 import File1
```

And when I run football/main.py, it works.

But when I run pytest, I get the error more or less like that:

```
football/file1.py:2: in <module>
from file2 import File2
E   ImportError: No module named 'file2'
```

So it imports correctly the 'file1.py' file but when that file imports 'file2.py' it raises the error that it can't import (although this import works when I run football/main.py without tests).

So how should all those imports be to make it all work and have no errors during tests?

Comment: Where is your `__init__.py`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about `__init__.py`. It's there, I just forgot to add this in the post. I will edit my post.

Comment: Add an empty `conftest.py` (not "context.py") in `Football` (project root directory). It will resolve the imports in tests.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add `__init__.py` to your Football/football directory for python package discovery. Then, one thing you could do is add a [setup.py](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) at your project's root level and within that use [find_packages()](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) to recursively find packages to add to the python path. You'll then have to pip install your project into the virtual environment before running your tests. Tools like [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) make accomplishing these steps easier by automatically setting up the virtual environment before calling your test commands.

Another option is to use the [monkeypatch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) fixture (a pytest builtin) and modify the PYTHONPATH for your tests. You could put this in your tests/conftest.py. Still you would need to create an `__init__.py` in your Football/football  directory.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)  # run this automatically before tests
def pythonpath(monkeypatch):
    path_to_project = "<path to your project root>"
    monkeypatch.setenv('PYTHONPATH', path_to_project)
```